# How to replace margin-left animation with transform in Jquery animate() to fix laggy multislider

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-animate

I'll preface this by saying my initial problem is difficult to reproduce.
Brief explanation of my problem following, question is at the bottom.

So I am using the Jquery multislider for a project.
Here is a link to it: [Multislider](https://www.multislider.info/)

Now my issue is that the animation of the moving elements seems to lag... Sometimes.
It jumps instead of moving smoothly.
The way the element works is by applying the `animate()` method to the first item and applies an inline `margin-left` property to the first `.item`

With some research I have found that CSS animations often cause problems when `margins` are used for the animation(among some other properties like top/bottom/left/right, as well as height/width) and that using `transform` is preferable.
So far so good.

This is the snippet in the javascript that creates the animation:

```
function singleLeft(){
        isItAnimating(function(){
            reTargetSlides();
            $imgFirst.animate(
                {
                    marginLeft: -animateDistance /* This is the part that causes me problems */
                }, {
                    duration: animateDuration,
                    easing: "swing",
                    complete: function(){
                        $imgFirst.detach().removeAttr('style').appendTo($msContent);
                        doneAnimating();
                    }
                }
            );
        });
    }

    function singleRight(){
        isItAnimating(function(){
            reTargetSlides();
            $imgLast.css('margin-left',-animateDistance).prependTo($msContent);
            $imgLast.animate(
                {
                    marginLeft: 0
                }, {
                    duration: animateDuration,
                    easing: "swing",
                    complete: function(){
                        $imgLast.removeAttr("style");
                        doneAnimating();
                    }
                }
            );
        });
    }
```

Now if I understand it correctly, I have to replace the `marginLeft: -animateDistance` portion with a transformX property, is that correct?
But I am failing to make it work.

**So my question is**, how can I replace the `marginLeft: -animateDistance` portion with `transform: translateX()` and add the `animateDistance` variable between the parentheses?

I have tried something like `transform: "translateX(-$(animateDistance))"`, but that just disables the animation entirely. 
Am I missing something?
I'm open for other suggestions to solve the issue of the laggy animation as well, this just is the conclusion I came to.

Comment: For anyone else who has this issue: If you have JavaScript that creates an animation by applying CSS in "gradually", make sure the element does not have any transitions applied to it. This will make the browser try to add transitions between each step, which in my case were fractions of pixels. 
So just add `transition: auto` and everything works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use animate with $(this) and [.css()](https://api.jquery.com/css/) if you use [step()](https://api.jquery.com/animate/#step)

```js
let test = "100";

$('div h2').animate({ pxNumber: test }, {
    step: function(pxNumber) {
      $(this).css('transform','translateX(-' + pxNumber + 'px )'); 
    },
    duration:'slow',
    easing: "swing",
    complete: function(){
      console.log('Animation done');
       // doneAnimating();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><h2>Move it</h2></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! There's still some issues to work out, but it looks good so far

Comment: Your welcome, validate my answer if it answer to your needs :) @SmilyLily

Comment: I am having an issue now that I can't figure out, the animation only seems to apply to the first element of the slider, do you have any idea why that could be? 
If I replace margin with transform, it should just work the same or not at all, right? 
But it just moves the first item out of view and the rest don't move.

Comment: do you target all your elements ? @SmilyLily

Comment: I changed the code to target all elements. The margin was only applied to the first element, but that doesn't work with the transform. 
That way the elements are moved to the left but then nothing. The slider just breaks. 
I am giving up at this point. 
I'm not even 100% sure if this is the right solution to my initial problem with the jerky animation. I will try to test it live and maybe it's just an issue I have to accept locally...

Comment: Okay since you answered my question I will leave it but I finally figured out the actual problem. Just in case anyone else has that issue: When you add css with JavaScript, MAKE SURE the element does NOT have a transition applied to it. This will interfere and cause the animation to appear laggy.